# Recommended way to convert String into Array of chars in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a bit new to Javascript and I would like to know the effective difference between Array.from(string) and string.split('').

```
const word = 'test';

const arrayFrom = Array.from(word);
const stringSplit = word.split('');

console.log(arrayFrom);
console.log(stringSplit);
```

In the script above, both logs are exactly the same:

```
[ 't', 'e', 's', 't' ]
[ 't', 'e', 's', 't' ]
```

Knowing that, which should I use? Is there any performance advance in using any of them?

Comment: what about `[...word]`? ;)

Comment: Your second way will work on almost any Browser. In my opinion, that is recommended to reach the largest audience.

Comment: In your case, I prefer `split()`

Comment: Why even bother? You can access the characters by index anyway, which is infinitely faster than converting to an array first, regardless of how you do it. "*Which should I use*" is off topic as answers will be opinion based.

Comment: Accented characters are still single characters and I am not considering the Non-English alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a quick profile in Node will tell you that `word.split('')` is the fastest, followed by `[...word]`, then `Array.from(word)`. This was my benchmark:

```js
const word = '1783638745638476548765873hdsgkfj';
console.time('arrayFrom');
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  const arrayFrom = Array.from(word);
}
console.timeEnd('arrayFrom');
console.time('split');
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  const stringSplit = word.split('');
}
console.timeEnd('split');
console.time('spread');
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  const spread = [...word];
}
console.timeEnd('spread');
```

And the results:

arrayFrom: 35.401ms

split: 1.349ms

spread: 5.862ms

That said, you generally shouldn't sweat the performance of such a thing unless  you are optimising some very critical section of code. It's six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: A regular expression does relatively decently too: `const fromRegex = word.match(/./g);` at 2.327ms vs 0.555ms for `split()`, faster than every other option except split.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN:

> Array.from() has an optional parameter mapFn, which allows you to execute a map function on each element of the array (or subclass object) that is being created. More clearly, Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg) has the same result as Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg), except that it does not create an intermediate array. This is especially important for certain array subclasses, like typed arrays, since the intermediate array would necessarily have values truncated to fit into the appropriate type.

Basically, `Array.from()` has more uses beyond what `Array.split` does. For your specific case, there is no performance or functional difference.

Answer (score 0):

The **Array.from()** method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

[reference for array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

[Medium reference for **from()**](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/javascript-array-from-53287c195487)

The **split()** method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

[reference for split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`String.split('')` results to be the most performant method.
Check this [jsperf benchmark](https://jsperf.app/tetuxo/2)